# Image won't load on lower android versions Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a mainpage which has 4 local images and it works fine on android 10 and i tested it on several phones but when installed it on my mom's phone which has android 7 on it one of the images on the mainpage won't load. i cant really understand why. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care also about the resolutions of the device. I had a rendering problem  of background images which I put in the default drawable folder (problems at the Samsung S7).

Try to adapt the properties of the image based on the device resolutions.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

So test if its Android version or device resolution problem.

Check the console output of the Android device by the Output Window of Visual Studio or the Android Device Monitor. Maybe you get a hint there!